# Add webform field programmatically

Tags: webforms, 9

In older versions of Webform (Drupal 7), the function `webform_component_insert()` can be used to add fields to a webform, for example inside a `hook_node_insert()` implementation, so they are added when the webform is created.

Does anyone know how to do that in Webform 6.x? I would like to add fields to webforms automatically after they are created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can alter a webform by modifying the YAML content of the config field `elements`:

```
use Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform;
use Drupal\Core\Serialization\Yaml;

  $webform = Webform::load('contact');
  $elements = Yaml::decode($webform->get('elements'));

  // add a field
  $elements['additional_field'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Additional field',
  ];

  $webform->set('elements', Yaml::encode($elements));
  $webform->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $webform  = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
       ->getStorage('webform')
       ->load(webform_16371); //enter webform id here
  $new_field = [
   'workflow'=>[ '#type' => 'webform_workflows_element',
   '#title' => 'Webform Workflow',
   '#required' => TRUE,
   '#workflow'=> 'webform_workflow', // Add any property
 ]];


 $new_element_arrangment = array_merge($webform->getElementsDecoded(), $new_field);
 $webform->setElements($new_element_arrangment)->save();
```